# Login to Windows with Teamviewer without entering Windows password

Tags: windows-7, windows, remote-desktop, passwords, teamviewer

I have a PC, that runs as a server 24/7. The PC is accessible locally true Windows remote desktop and outside of the network whit the teamviewer. The remote desktop is used only by me and the teamviewer is used by some other people.

I have set up unattended  access through team viewer and gave each user a unique password so they can log in. They do not use accounts though. Each time a user logs in they need to enter the Windows password (login) and its a bit of a bother.

Is there a way to set Windows or teamviewer so that remote connections would not need to enter the password without removing it?

I need to log in to this specific account because it runs a test database and has to be up 24/7.

Comment: Configure PC to never logout of the user.  Configure the PC to automatically log into the user.  Setup team viewer to automatically start when logged into the user.  Doing all this will make the system insecure and anyone with physical access the machine will have complete and total control over the data on it.

Comment: Thank you for the replay, but this would compromise the security of the pc even more. I guess that i leave it the way it is for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the Windows desktop you will need to log in locally and stay logged in. You can't lock it or anything like that. If the server is kept logged in locally when the TV session connects there will be no Windows prompt for password.

Comment: Thank you for the replay. Its not a windows server. It runs on windows 7. The PC is turned on but not loged in since no one is accessing it localy. No screen keyboard .... . Would the same apply ?

Comment: Yes, the same applies.@MarifarmIT

Comment: I will try it out.

Comment: Sounds good, send any questions/upvote/mark as answer/etc as needed :)